# Profile shared object without recompiling main program

Tags: c++, postgresql, profiling, shared-libraries, callgrind

I currently am developing a shared lilbrary for loading into PostgreSQL (as C-Language functions, see [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/xfunc-c.html)). Now I would like to profile the function in this library without recompiling PostgreSQL itself.

I tried callgrind using

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind path/to/postgres arguments-to-postgres
```

This gives me profiling information for PostgreSQL itself, but fails to log the shared library I am interested in.

I also tried `sprof`, but I have no idea how to get that one working.

Any ideas would be highly appriciated.

P.S.: Please do not suggest just pausing the application in a debugger. With function runtimes way below 0.01 seconds I need more detailled results.

Comment: Just a short update: Upgrading to PostgreSQL 9.0 and Ubuntu 11.4 did the trick. Now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Using callgrind should work as expected. To test this I setup a simple project using a simple library and main functionMakefile:

```
CFLAGS=-fpic
exe:exe.o lib.so
        cc -o exe exe.o lib.so
lib.so:lib.o
        cc -shared lib.o -o lib.so
clean:
        rm -f exe lib.so *.o
```

lib.c is a simple library containing 2 functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void someOtherFunction() { printf("someOtherFunction\n"); }
void someFunction() { printf("someFunction\n"); someOtherFunction(); }
```

exe.c is a very simple executable:

```
int someFunction();
void main() { someFunction(); }
```

Use the Makefile to build the executable and run it using valgrind like so:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PWD valgrind --tool=callgrind ./exe
```

If you examine the callgrind output, you will find the profiling data for both functions in the shared library. If you cannot see these functions you may be using a non-standard environment that does not support this functionality. I'm using Linux Mint 11 x64, with the latest patches.

Comment: Thanks for your input. This minimal example works. However, in my case above there are two major differences: The library is not linked at compile time, but at runtime using `dlopen`. Furthermore, my Postgres build has no debugging information enabled. Thus, callgrind seems to get kinda lost within the called functions.

Comment: PostgreSQL is open source - recompile it with symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Point 1: Valgrind seems to have issues with privilege escalation, which is VERY likely to be performed by Postgres, see http://www.mail-archive.com/valgrind-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg02355.html

Point 2: Have you tried to prove (e.g. with strace) that your SL is actually loaded in the same process? Have you tried to --trace-children=yes?

Point 3: I've tried to modify the test by compiling exe.o and exe with -g0 and using dlopen to load the file, i.e.:

```
all: exe lib.so
exe : exe.c 
        cc -g0 -o exe exe.c -ldl

lib.so:lib.c
        cc -shared lib.c -o lib.so
clean:
        rm -f exe lib.so *.o
```

and

```
#include 
#include 

void main() { 
    void *handle;
    void (*p)();
    int i;

    handle = dlopen("./lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if ( ! handle ) { printf("Object not found\n"); return; }
    p = dlsym(handle, "someFunction");
    if ( ! p ) { printf("Function not found\n"); return; }
    for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) (*p)();
    dlclose(handle);
}
```

Works with callgrind. Maybe Postgres is not using -ldl to open the object files?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. Regarding Point 2: The strace output does contain only one call to execve, which as far as I understand suggests that everything is running in the same process. However, adding --trace-children=yes has no effect. I will have a look at your point 1 later, now my time is running short.

Comment: Got time now to look into your first point. This also seems very likely for me to be the cause of trouble. Which leaves one question: Any other suggestions?

Comment: Running postgres as root to prevent privilege escalation?

Comment: Postgres prohibits running as root. However, I can start it in single user mode with it's own user. This does not solve the problem, however.

Comment: Does it still call setuid()? If yes, you might be able to solve the issue by LD_PRELOAD -ing away the setuid call.

Comment: Good question. Just had a short look: It does not call setuid().

Comment: Well, fair enough. I am out of ideas, sorry :-(.

Comment: Still, thank you for your ideas. There were quite a few nice ones!